# no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exists so that Row conforms to Iterable<? extends U>

Tags: java, generics, rx-java, guava

I have a method that returns an Observable of ResultSet:

```
public static Observable<ResultSet> queryAllAsObservable(Session session, String query, Object... partitionKeys) {
    List<ResultSetFuture> futures = sendQueries(session, query, partitionKeys);
    Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.io();
    List<Observable<ResultSet>> observables = Lists.transform(futures, (ResultSetFuture future) -> Observable.fromFuture(future, scheduler));
    return Observable.merge(observables);
}
```

Now I need to create a version of this method that returns an Observable of Row instead. This is what I've tried:

```
public static Observable<Row> queryAllAsRowObservable(Session session, String query, Object... partitionKeys) {
    List<ResultSetFuture> futures = sendQueries(session, query, partitionKeys);
    Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.io();
    List<Observable<ResultSet>> observables = Lists.transform(futures, (ResultSetFuture future) -> Observable.fromFuture(future, scheduler));
    return Observable.merge(observables).flatMapIterable(item -> item.one());
}
```

But `item -> item.one()` is marked by an error:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exists so that Row conforms to Iterable<? extends U>
```

Comment: Why are you using `flatMapIterable`?  What do you think the type of `Observable.merge(observables)` is?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am using flatMapIterable because I am following this tutorial: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries, which at the end has this challenge and says to do it with flatMapIterable

Comment: flatMapIterable does not work at this point. Either use something different or change the code leading up to it. What you have right there is appropriate for a map, not a flatMap.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it's working for me with map. Please wirte it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMapIterable` has the wrong type for what you're trying to do at the point you're trying to do it.  You could use `map` instead of `flatMapIterable`, or reconsider your use of `merge`.